# Can we find three sets $A, B, C$ given the constraints $a+b=c, a, b$ and $c$ denoting the elements of sets $A, B, C$ respectively.

Tags: combinatorics

Regarding the question, I was curious that if there's any means to find a relation between such sets in a "general form" without using "trial and error" on the elements.

Does any such general form exist ?

Thank you.

Comment: My gut instinct is to define a relation $R$ on $A, B$ such that $R \subseteq A \times B$ where $(a,b) \in R \Leftrightarrow (a + b) \in C$. (That is $aRb$ - $a$ is related to $b$ - if and only if $a+b=c$ for some $c \in C$.  I guess similar analogues could also follow for relations on $A, C$ and $B, C$ but using subtraction. Or is that the "trial and error" approach you mentioned (or something in that vein)?

Comment: Yes I guess..This is the trial and error method I've been mentioning..